# How do I select an element based on the state of another element in the page with CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have elements that can reflect different states, either triggered by the user (`:hover`, `:focus`, etc.) or manipulated by the server (`data-status="finished"`, `disabled`, etc.).

I can target the element that has a changed state, but I can't seem to find a way to target other elements in the DOM based on the state of the element in question.

Example:

```
<section>
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div data-status="finished">Element 2</div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div class="blink">Element 5</div>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div class="spin">Element 4</div>
    ...
</section>
```

or just render the elements with proper styles server-side.

Is there a CSS selector that would let me specify which elements should get selected based on the target element's state?

Something like:

```
div[data-status~=finished]:affect(.blink, .spin)
```

that would allow me to also **target elements that don't have the same parent** with CSS only?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The general answer to the canonical question

> How do I select an element based on the state of another element in the page with CSS?

is that it depends on exactly three conditions:

1. whether the state of these elements can be represented using simple selectors,
2. whether a structural relationship can be expressed between these two elements using combinators to form a *single complex selector*, and
3. whether the element that you want to target can be made the subject of the resulting complex selector.

While the [current Selectors standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors) has some interesting and sometimes potentially powerful features, the way it is designed makes it extremely limited in area #2 (with #3 being a direct consequence). Some of these limited possibilities are enumerated in other answers, e.g. through the most basic use of child and sibling combinators, [clever use of dynamic pseudo-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708741/how-do-i-select-an-element-based-on-the-state-of-another-element-in-the-page-wit/28738082#28738082) (which actually relates to condition #1), or [a combination of both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708741/how-do-i-select-an-element-based-on-the-state-of-another-element-in-the-page-wit/28708762#28708762).

The problem given in the question, on the other hand, cannot be solved using what is currently available in Selectors for this reason. Most of this boils down to the lack of either a parent selector and/or a previous sibling selector, both of which may seem like trivial features, but have certain implications that make them difficult to define or implement well. In summary:

1. Yes, the state of these elements can be represented using simple selectors: `div` and `[data-status~=finished]` for the former, and `.blink` and `.spin` for the latter two.
2. The first element can be represented by `section > div[data-status~=finished]`, and the two subject elements can be represented by `section + section > .blink` and `section + section > .spin` respectively. The problem is that it's not possible to write a complex selector incorporating all of these structures, because combinators are one-way, and there is no parent counterpart to the child combinator to join them at the first `section` element.
3. Assuming the answer to the first two questions is also "yes", each of `.blink` and `.spin` can be made the subject of its *own* complex selector. (But more on that in the next section.)

If you've been directed to this question, chances are the problem you're trying to solve, like the one given above, cannot be solved with Selectors due to these limitations.

The [upcoming standard](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4) boasts some new features that will greatly enrich selector syntax and potentially open it (and CSS) up to a host of new possibilities, including a possible solution to the example problem. All of these things will be covered in the following sections, but first I'll explain what each condition means and how it relates to the given example:

#### Element states, and structural relationships between elements

The defining characteristic of a selector is that it represents a certain structure of one or more elements in the document tree. This isn't just something I made up — you can actually find this description in the [informative overview of the Selectors standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors):

> A Selector represents a structure. This structure can be used as a condition (e.g. in a CSS rule) that determines which elements a selector matches in the document tree, or as a flat description of the HTML or XML fragment corresponding to that structure.
>
> Selectors may range from simple element names to rich contextual representations.

Each element is represented by a sequence of one or more simple selectors. This sequence is known as a compound selector (I'm using terminology from Selectors 4 here as it is much clearer than what is used in Selectors 3 — see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848556/correct-terms-and-words-for-sections-and-parts-of-selectors/9849403#9849403) for a non-exhaustive list of terms).

Each simple selector represents a certain state of an element. There are simple selectors for matching the type (or tag name) of an element, a class name, an ID, or an arbitrary attribute. There are also pseudo-classes, which represent abstractions and other special states not directly represented within the document tree, such as the order and position of an element in its hierarchy (`:nth-child()`, `:nth-of-type()`), user interactions (`:hover`, `:active`, `:focus`, `:checked`), the visitedness of a hyperlink (`:link`, `:visited`), and much more.

In the given example, the `div` element with a `data-status` attribute whose space-delimited value contains `finished` can be represented with a type selector and an attribute selector:

```
div[data-status~=finished]
```

If you want the selector to apply only when the pointer is over this element, simply throw in a `:hover` pseudo-class:

```
div[data-status~=finished]:hover
```

Compound selectors are linked via combinators to form complex selectors. These combinators, the `>`, `+` and `~` symbols that you may be familiar with, express a relationship between the elements represented by each compound selector. With these two tools alone, you're already able to create some very interesting results as shown in the other answers here. I explain these basics in even further depth in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131993/changing-the-properties-of-another-element-using-pseudo-selectors/28133840#28133840).

In the given example, the following structural relationships can be established:

- The first `section` element is the parent of `div[data-status~=finished]`. This is represented using the [child combinator `>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean/3225905#3225905):

  ```
  section > div[data-status~=finished]
  ```
- The second `section` immediately follows the first one as its sibling. This is represented using the [adjacent sibling combinator `+`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225891/what-does-the-greater-than-sign-css-selector-mean/3225905#3225905):

  ```
  section + section
  ```
- Additionally, the second `section` is the parent of both `.blink` and `.spin`. This can be represented using two selectors, one for each child:

  ```
  section + section > .blink, 
  section + section > .spin
  ```

  Why are two selectors required? In this case it's mainly because there is currently no syntax for [subgrouping two compound selectors into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800779/why-cant-you-group-descendants-in-a-css-selector/11786102#11786102), so you will have to represent each child element separately. The upcoming Selectors 4 standard introduces a `:matches()` pseudo-class that will provide this very subgrouping functionality:

  ```
  section + section > :matches(.blink, .spin)
  ```

Now, since every compound selector in a complex selector represents one element, and thus `section + section` represents two elements that are siblings, `section > div` represents a parent and a child, and `section + section > div` represents a child of a next-sibling, you would think that a parent combinator and a previous-sibling combinator are quite redundant. So why do we commonly get these questions:

- [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)
- [Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

And, more importantly, why is the answer to both of these questions **no**? The reason is addressed in the next point:

#### Subject of a selector

The [subject](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#subject) of a selector is always represented by the rightmost compound selector. For example, the selector `section + section > div` represents three elements, of which `div` is the subject. You might say that the `div` is *selected*, or *targeted*, as in the question, but if you've ever wondered if there was a proper term, it's known as the subject of the selector.

In a CSS rule, styles are applied to the element represented by the subject of the selector. Any child boxes and pseudo-element boxes inherit the styles from this element where appropriate. (The exception is if the subject of the selector includes a pseudo-element, in which case the styles are applied directly to the pseudo-element only.)

Taking the selectors from the previous section, we have the following:

- The subject of `section > div[data-status~=finished]` is `div[data-status~=finished]`.
- The subject of `section + section` is the *second* `section` selector.
- The subjects of `section + section > .blink, section + section > .spin` are `.blink` and `.spin` respectively.
- Using `:matches()`, the subject of `section + section > :matches(.blink, .spin)` is `:matches(.blink, .spin)`.

It might seem therefore that we do need a parent selector or a previous-sibling selector. But remember that selectors can already represent complex structures. Instead of simply adding new combinators that work opposite of existing ones, it makes sense to seek out a more flexible solution, and that is exactly what the CSSWG has been doing.

Which brings us to the following from the original question:

> Is there a CSS selector that would let me specify which elements should get selected based on target element state?

The answer to this is no, and will remain no. However, in the earlier drafts of Selectors 4 (from the [FPWD](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/#subject) up to [the latest working draft from May 2013](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject)), there was a proposal for a new feature that would let you pick any of the compound selectors other than the rightmost one, and designate that as the subject of the selector.

#### A potential solution

However, the subject indicator was recently removed in favor of the `:has()` pseudo-class (that was in turn [adopted from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector)). I speculate on a likely reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982922/latest-on-css-parent-selector/27983098#27983098):

> The reason `:has()` is more versatile is because, with the subject selector, it was never made clear in any draft if a single complex selector could have more than one subject selector (since a single complex selector can only ever have one subject) and/or if functional pseudo-classes such as `:matches()` accepted the subject selector. But because a pseudo-class is a simple selector, you know that `:has()` can be accepted anywhere a pseudo-class is accepted.

So while you cannot change the subject of a selector, `:has()` will completely write off the need to do so, due to its pseudo-class nature. And the best part is that it does this — *and then some* — all without fundamentally changing selector syntax.

In fact, the example problem *can be solved* using Selectors 4's `:has()`:

```
/* Combined with the :matches() example from above */
section:has(> div[data-status~=finished]) + section > div:matches(.blink, .spin)
```

Notice the use of a child combinator: this scopes the relative selector argument to just children of the first `section`. Yes, this is the elusive "parent selector" that Web developers the world over have been wanting for years.

And since `:has()` comes from jQuery, you can use it *today*, although `:matches()` doesn't exist yet so you'll have to replace that with a call to `.filter()` in the meantime:

```js
$('section:has(> div[data-status~=finished]) + section > div')
    .filter('.blink, .spin')
    .css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div data-status="finished">Element 2</div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div class="blink">Element 5</div>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div class="spin">Element 4</div>
    ...
</section>
```

It's so versatile, that it will also allow you to not only "target elements that don't have the same parent", but also elements that are completely unrelated, including elements whose positions in the document tree may vary irrespective of one another. This will *effectively eliminate* condition #2 above, although doing so comes with a major caveat which I'll get to in a second. For example, if we assume that the `div` elements in question may appear anywhere with no structural relation to one another, `:has()` allows you to do:

```
:root:has(div[data-status~=finished]) div:matches(.blink, .spin)
```

... which finds `div.blink, div.spin` when `div[data-status~=finished]` exists *anywhere in the document tree*, since any element in the document tree must be a descendant of the document root element.

Now, the caveat that I mentioned, is that using arbitrary complex selectors with `:has()` can have serious performance implications, which is why for the longest time parent selectors were never implemented, and both the subject indicator and `:has()` have not been implemented yet. The latter two in particular are problematic because the "rightmost compound selector" definition [serves as the basis of mainstream CSS selector engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left), and these two features seek to challenge it altogether.

This is also why `:has()` is tentatively excluded from the [fast profile](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#profiles) and may therefore not be usable in CSS, as it requires real-time selector matching during page rendering, a situation that is undeniably performance-critical. It will still be accessible through the DOM methods [`querySelector()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-parentnode-queryselector), [`querySelectorAll()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-parentnode-queryselectorall) and [`matches()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-element-matches) (and any selector libraries that happen to make use of them), however.

That said, the CSSWG has [plans](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Feb/0306.html) to test limited variations of `:has()` (e.g. with a single child combinator or sibling combinator) to see if they can be implemented well enough to be included in CSS, which will fulfill the *vast* majority of use cases, *including* the first example above.

#### Conclusion

Unfortunately, CSS selector syntax remains extremely limited today; however, new proposals to the standard are set to bring powerful new possibilities, and a handful of these additions are based on features that selector libraries such as jQuery already offer. Here's hoping that implementations will support these new features for use in CSS.

Comment: I'll accept this one as answer since it cover the topic as a whole. Reffer to the rest of answers for samples.

Comment: I don't think this answer is long enough Bolty.

Comment: Fantastic answer.

Comment: A great explanation of why the answer to these questions will always be **no**. This is why it is called Cascading Style Sheets for a good reason - it flows from top to bottom and does not need the entire DOM to be ready.

Comment: @nobug: That's a common misconception. The cascade has nothing to do with the top-down nature of page loads.

Answer (score 17):

You are very limited on what you can achieve with the current state of CSS.

In short - you can make CSS elements react to a state change of an element, if they have the same parent AND are siblings, or the parent's children.

---

The state of an element in CSS is handled by [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), which cover most of the typical interactions that a browser handles based on user input.

While this enables you to handle the visual look of the current state of an element and its children in the DOM tree, you still can't make other non-child elements react (with a visual change of style) to the current state of your element, since CSS does not offer a specific type of selector to do that in a flexible way.

You can, however, combine the pseudo-classes with other types of CSS selectors and make this work in certain situations (I will use the hover state since it's the most obvious):

**pseudo class + adjacent sibling selector**

Adjacent sibling selector matches if `element1` and `element2` share the same parent in the document tree and `element1` immediately precedes `element2`. 
([W3C specification of Adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors))

```css
div:hover + div {
    background:red;
}
```

```html
Hover on elements:
<div>Element 1</div>
<div>Element 2</div>
<div>Element 3</div>
<div>Element 4</div>
<div>Element 5</div>
```

**Pseudo class + General sibling combinator**

This combination works the same as the adjacent sibling selector, except that the element being selected doesn't need to immediately succeed the first element; it can appear anywhere after it.

```css
div:hover ~ div {
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div>Element 1</div>
<section>Element 2</section>
<em>Element 3</em>
<div>Element 4</div>
<div>Element 5</div>
```

**Attribute selector + General sibling combinator / Attribute selector + adjacent sibling selector**

States of DOM elements are often stored in data attributes. CSS offers you an attribute selector, which lets you apply style based on the value of an attribute.

The following example sets a lower opacity to all elements following the element with a status of »finished«:

```css
div[data-status~=finished] ~ div {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div>Element 1</div>
<div data-status="finished">Element 2</div>
<div>Element 3</div>
<div>Element 4</div>
<div>Element 5</div>
```

**:not()**

In certain cases, `:not()` could help you select all other elements that don't have the state in question active, however, non-simple selectors are not yet supported in CSS3 in :not(), though they are proposed in the new draft [Selectors Level 4 draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#negation). So currently, you can **not** do `div:not(.class, .class)` – since only simple selectors are supported ( type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class).

---

In the end you can build some complex selectors that may achieve what you want to do, but are usually pretty static, and will probably stop working as soon as the DOM structure changes, but for corner cases you may solve the problem. [MDN's pseudo selector list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) can be handy when combining them.

Unfortunately, at the moment of writing this, you will still have to handle it outside CSS for a solid solution.

Comment: ~ Not just awesome, but incredibly useful ~ Thanks for taking the time to write this! ++

Comment: FYI: `:not()` allows use of attribute as well type selector in CSS 3 already, http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn – it just has to be a “simple” selector, so you can not use combinations of multiple selectors.

Comment: I wish this example didn't just style base on `div` because it's confusing which element is actually being styled. It would be more useful if the styles were based on classes and each div in the example had a distinct class.

Answer (score 6):

As @easwee has already posted a nice answer , I would not repeat any pseudo-class selectors discussed by him,

---

A new pseudo class we have now, in css3 is **:target**.

> The `:target` pseudo selector in CSS matches when the hash in the
>   URL and the id of an element are the same.

(The specific use of :target is to style element which is targeted and curruntly visible on top of the viewport)

So this can actually be (mis)used, based on user interaction(click specifically), to change other element styles, when used with another pseudo classes or sibling selectors.

For example:  target child  of sibling of parent.

```css
:target section div[data-status=finished] {
  color: red;
}
a,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
section {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<nav id='nav'>
  <h4>This is Navigation section</h4>
  <section>
    sibling
    <div><a href='#nav'>(child)click me to target child  of sibling of parent</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    sibling
    <div data-status="finished">(child)I am child of parent of sibling</div>
  </section>

</nav>
```

---

Note that it wasn't possible to style parent element, or any other element in the html hierarchy before `:target` was introduced. It is still new, and doing something like this(selecting another element based on click of another element) is not the reason why `:target` was designed for.

**Disadvantages**:

1. Targeting elements using target, will require not use too much in a single page or it will make you navigate throughout the page unwantedly.
2. The style targetted for element remains on it untill the target remains same.

you can play with this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hduemee3/1/)**