# Make Rails 'field_with_error' not apply to certain inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using some CSS form elements that use :checked styling, such as.

```
input:checked + label {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Where the corresponding HTML (simplified for example) would be:

```
<input type="checkbox">
<label>My Checkbox</label>
```

Unfortunately, :checked styling wreaks havoc when .field_with_errors comes into play, because it creates a div around both elements, like so:

```
<div class="field_with_errors">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="field_with_errors">
    <label>My Checkbox</label>
</div>
```

As far as I know, given that HTML structure it's no longer possible to style the label based on whether the checkbox is checked.

I can't entirely remove `field_with_errors` on either labels or inputs, because legacy aspects of the application I'm working on rely on it.

So I'm wondering if it is possible to simply make it so that `field_with_errors` doesn't wrap elements if they are hidden. I don't know a ton about Ruby/Rails yet, but I know (of course) that it runs pre-page-load. I'm still hoping beyond hope that maybe I'm not thinking of something :-D.

Any alternative but similarly-effective approaches are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use raw HTML and generate the check box and label yourself, without using the view helpers. The name would be `model[field]` and you have to make sure that it sets the correct value when it is not selected because browsers don't send back unselected checkboxes.

Comment: Wow, it sounds like this might work! My current radio button is structured like: `<%= f.radio_button :my_field, index %>` (it's inside a loop, thus `index` is present). how to get I get the name from the `:my_field` var?

Comment: Look at the source of the HTML that Rails generates in your browser and copy that.

Comment: I could do that--but I'd prefer (if possible) to have it still dynamically pulled from the `:my_field` var. I have no idea what `:my_field` holds since `debug()` doesn't seem to show. Pardon my ignorance!

Comment: `:my_field` is the name of the field! The value is in `@model.my_field`. The name of the HTML element is `model[my_field]`.

Comment: Oooh, haha. Okay. Why does it have a colon before it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a css rule that redefines a div with class field_with_errors to not be display block.

```
div.field_with_errors { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: The `display: block;` isn't the issue. The issue is that you can't use CSS selectors on the `:checked` element to reach into the child div of a separate container. Thanks nonetheless for the input!

Comment: You should be able to write css rules that can still apply. Alternatively you could try not using a rails helper to generate the label. Something like <label><%= f.check_box ... %></label>

Comment: Unfortunately the CSS isn't possible. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32793254/1809762 But yes! The raw solution is what I went with!

Comment: I see. If you are willing to use JavaScript then you could bind an event to the checkbox (using jQuery or the like) and have it change a class on the label which you could then style. Not pure CSS, but another option.