# HTML CSS: Switch/Change background color of div, color of label text on radio button selection

Tags: html, css

I have input and label inside a div. There are two divs div1 and div2. I want to change background color of div and color of label text when selecting corresponding radio button.

Div color want to change from **red** to **blue**

label text color **black** to **yellow**

I have written below HTML and CSS for this:

HTML:

```
<div class="main_div">
    <div class="div1">
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1" id="yes" /><label for="yes">Yes, It is</label>
    </div>
    <div class="spaceDiv"></div>
    <div class="div2">
        <input type="radio" name="group1" value="2" id="no" /><label for="no">Not at all</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1, .div2 {
    background: red;
    display: block;
    height: 3em;

}

.div1, .div2 input {
    padding: 1em;
}

.div2, .div1 input {
    padding: 1em;
}

.div1 label {
    padding: .9em;
}

.div2 label {
    padding: .9em;
}


.spaceDiv {
    background: #fff;
    height: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: It is not possible by pure css. You have to use javascript or jquey.

Comment: @alirezasafian, how?

Comment: [This is a jquery solution](http://jsfiddle.net/7h22zqvp/).

Comment: Alternate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708741/how-do-i-select-an-element-based-on-the-state-of-another-element-in-the-page-wit

Comment: @cimmanon, I am sorry but I don`t think it is a duplicate.

Comment: @VicJordan How do you figure it's not a duplicate?  You're asking how to style the div element, which is an ancestor/parent of the input element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution, which uses the `:after` pseudo-element on the `label` so it covers the entire `div`.  The background has been moved from the `div` to this pseudo-element.  When the `input` is checked, the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) (~) is used to change the background color of the pseudo-element as well as the text color of the `label`.

> how I can vertical align input and label inside the div? I have used padding stuff which is not correct

Since there's only one line of text, setting `line-height` equal to `height` will cause vertical alignment.  You can then remove the padding:

```
.div1,
.div2 {
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
.div1,
.div2 {
  display: block;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  position: relative;
}

.spaceDiv {
  background: #fff;
  height: 0.5em;
}

label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}

input:checked ~ label:after {
  background: blue;
}

input:checked ~ label {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_div">
  <div class="div1">
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1" id="yes" />
    <label for="yes">Yes, It is</label>
  </div>
  <div class="spaceDiv"></div>
  <div class="div2">
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="2" id="no" />
    <label for="no">Not at all</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what i wanted. One more small question, how I can vertical align input and label inside the div? I have used padding stuff which is not correct :(

Comment: @VicJordan If it answered your question, please click the check mark next to the answer to signify that. It will give both you and the answerer some reputation

Comment: @ZachSaucier, thank you for your comment. I have upvoted the question as this is partial solution and also this is working standalone as it is but in my main code is it not working. I am waiting for the @Rick`s response. I will accept answer once it will be resolved

Comment: @VicJordan It seems to me that he answered the question you have asked. If you're asking a separate question, feel free to ask it separately

Comment: @ZachSaucier, understand. Thanks. But why people downvoted my question? :(

Comment: See my update regarding your vertical alignment question.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/mwbbcyja/58/

```
input:checked + label {
    background-color:red;
}
```