# How to select a div inside another element when a checkbox input is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a checkbox that I need when it's checked to show a div inside another element (not next to the checkbox it's inside a div that is next to it's parent)

```
 <nav>
   <div class='container'>
     <label class="tog" for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"></input> //This is the checkbox
   </div>
 </nav>
 <div class='container'>
   <div class='select'> // This is the div that I want to select when checkbox is checked
   </div>
 </div>
```

I tried these selectors but didn't work:

```
#toggle:checked   ~ .select{display:block}
#toggle:checked   + .select{display:block}
```

Comment: cannot be done. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817801/2119863

Answer (score 2):

There is not parent selector in CSS. If you can change the HTML, move the input to the same level of `nav` and the div's `.container`. Hide the input, which is controlled by the label, and using CSS sibling and parent rules you can control the div `display` property:

```css
#toggle {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#toggle:checked + nav .tog {
  color: red;
}

#toggle:not(:checked) ~ .container > .select {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">

<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <label class="tog" for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="select"> // This is the div that I want to select when checkbox is checked
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem with JS easily.

```
var input = document.getElementById('toggle');
var select = document.querySelectorAll('.select')[0];
input.onchange = function(){
   select.style.display = this.checked? 'block': 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but if you need to show/hide a div based on the status of a checkbox, you can try this

```
    <nav>
        <div class='container'>
            <label class="tog" for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"></input> //This is the checkbox
        </div>
    </nav>

<div class='container'>
    <div class='select' id="div-to-show" style="display:none">
    </div>
</div>

var check = document.getElementById('toggle');
check.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ){ 
    if( check.checked === true ){ 
        document.getElementById('div-to-show').style.display = 'block'; 
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('div-to-show').style.display = 'none';
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

The key part of your problem is here

> it's inside a div that is next to it's parent

This can't be done with CSS right now, as the target needs to be within the same parent. You can look [easwee's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28708762/2123956) to get a little more in-depth explanation, or [BoltClock's answer to get MUCH more in-depth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28793064/2123956).

Obviously, this can be done with Javascript if you want to go down that route, but it sounded like you wanted a CSS answer.