# With CSS, how do I hide all child elements except the first classless div that contains a child with a specific class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this HTML setup:

```
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="text"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With CSS, is it possible to hide all of the child elements of ".main" except the first classless div that contains the ".image" class div?

Answer (score 1):

Do you absolutely require the "contains an `.image`" condition? If so, you won't be able to do this since [there is no parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) (see also [How do I select an element based on the state of another element in the page with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708741/how-do-i-select-an-element-based-on-the-state-of-another-element-in-the-page-wit)).

If every classless child element of `.main` is guaranteed to contain an `.image` and every child element that has a class is guaranteed not to do so, write selectors based on this assumption instead, since you won't be able to construct selectors based on the "contains an `.image`" condition. Use a sibling combinator to exclude the first classless element:

```css
.main > div[class], .main > div:not([class]) ~ div:not([class]) {
  display: none;
}
```

But if — and this seems likely — not every classless element is guaranteed to contain an `.image` or not every element that has a class is guaranteed not to do so, the answer loops back to "not possible with pure CSS".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this css selector `:not(:first-child)`

```css
.main div:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="image">This should be visible</div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">This should be hidden</div>
  <div class="text">This should be hidden</div>
  <div>
    <div class="image">This should be hidden</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I considered this route, but in some cases, the div containing ".image" may not always be the first child and I need the first element that contains ".image" to be visible.