# Pure CSS conditional styling - is there such a thing?

Tags: css, conditional-statements, state

Is it possible, without SASS, LESS, Javascript - just pure CSS to do something similiar to:

```
.B
{
    display: none;
}

.A:empty
{
     display: none;

     .B
     {
         display: block;
     }
}
```

So that when class 'A' is empty do something else with container 'B'?
Or that when class 'A' is having some state - do something else with container B?

Examples:

```
Hover A -> Hide B
Hide B -> Show C
C Empty -> Show D
```

I've tried finding the correct terms for these states but haven't found anything yet - if there is any?

**Non dependant:**

I don't want the classes to be dependant upon eachother.

```
<div class="A"><div class="B"></div></div>
```

...is not a solution.

```
<div class="A"></div>
<div class="B">Show me when condition in A is reached<div>
```

Since then I can just do whatever I wanted fine. I want class A to be on some part of the page and class B inside some other container somewhere else - non relative to class A.

Comment: CSS is all about conditional styling using selectors. What you're asking is whether some specific combinations are possible. The answer is not all of them are, because selectors have a number of limitations to them. The concepts are explored in depth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708741/how-do-i-select-an-element-based-on-the-state-of-another-element-in-the-page-wit). In short it's all about the structure. Parent and previous-sibling combinations mostly aren't possible.

Comment: This kind of things are best done with javascript.

Comment: There is no conditional CSS, but you may use a "sibling selector" to change look and fill of elements in the same container. Here is a working demo: [Sibling selector](http://cssdeck.com/labs/jri9mfef)

Answer (score 2):

> edit: to add more info

Every time someone tells you something doesn't exist, isn't worth doing or better to just do it like they do. DOUBLE DOWN ON YOUR RESEARCH.

Links:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/
- https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-when-else/
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp
- https://logichop.com/docs/logic-hop-conditional-css/

Example:

```
 <style type="text/css">
      /* year comes last */
      time[datetime]:after {
        float: right;
        content: attr(datetime);
      }

      /* month and day come first */
      time[datetime*="-"] {
        float: left;
      }

      /* Months (non-USA) */
      time[datetime^="01-"]:after {
        content: "jan/";
      }

      ...rules for the other months go here...

      time[datetime^="12-"]:after {
        content: "dec/";
      }

      /* Days (non-USA) */
      time[datetime$="-01"]:before {
        content: "1/";
      }

      ...rules for the other days go here...

      time[datetime$="-31"]:before {
        content: "31/";
      }

      /* Months (USA) */
      *[lang="en-US"] time[datetime^="01-"]:before {
        content: "jan/";
      }

      ...rules for the other months go here...

      *[lang="en-US"] time[datetime^="12-"]:before {
        content: "dec/";
      }

      /* Days (USA) */
      *[lang="en-US"] time[datetime$="-01"]:after {
        content: "1/";
      }

      ...rules for the other days go here...

      *[lang="en-US"] time[datetime$="-31"]:after {
        content: "31/";
      }

  </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

No CSS does not support any pre-built conditions similar to what you are describing, sorry

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way. The following condition can be achieved, when the element has both A and B classes on it. Another way is wrapping elements with those classes in another tag, like

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="B"></div>
</div>
```

, then doing following in .css:

`.wrapper.A:hover + .B {...}`

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">One</div>
  <div class="B">Two</div>
  <div class="C">Three</div>
  <div class="D">Four</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container > div {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 200ms all;
}
.A {
  left: 10px;
}
.B {
  left: 120px;
}
.C {
  left: 230px;
}
.D {
  left: 340px;
}
.A:hover ~ .B {
  background-color: green;
}
.A:hover ~ .C {
  opacity: 0;
}
.A:hover ~ .D {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.B:hover ~ .C {
  background-color: green;
}
.B:hover ~ .D {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Working demo: [Sibling selector](http://cssdeck.com/labs/jri9mfef)

Comment: Don't want the classes to be dependant upon being wrapped in a parent class. I want class A and B to stand separate. It does not seem to be the case here?